# How to parcel an Object with an ArrayList with other Object which have a Reverence to the first Object

Tags: android, parcelable

It's a little bit complex.

I've Object 'A' which have an ArrayList of Object 'B'

Object 'B' have a Reference to Object 'A'.

When I'm starting to parcel, then follows a StackoverflowError.

Is there a Workarround to fix it.

Here my classes:

**Freizeit.java**

```
public class Freizeit implements Parcelable{


private List<Tag> tage;

public static final String FREIZEIT = "freizeit";


private Freizeit (Parcel in) {
    readFromParcel(in);
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeTypedList(this.tage);
}

public void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    in.readTypedList(this.tage, Tag.CREATOR);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Freizeit> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Freizeit>() {

    @Override
    public Freizeit createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Freizeit (source);
    }

    @Override
    public Freizeit[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Freizeit[size];
    }
};
```

}

**Tag.java**

```
public class Tag implements Parcelable {

private Freizeit freizeit;

public Tag (Freizeit freizeit) {
    this.freizeit = freizeit;
}

private Tag (Parcel in) {
    readFromParcel(in);
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeParcelable(this.freizeit, flags);
}

public void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    this.freizeit = in.readParcelable(Freizeit.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Tag> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Tag>() {

    @Override
    public Tag createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Tag (source);
    }

    @Override
    public Tag[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Tag[size];
    }
};
```

Sorry for my bad english...

Has anyone an idea? Thx.